# index.vue does not render as a ssr when first call get started (nuxt 3)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I have an issue like for days and there no solution I can find.

I have web site that the index.vue must be ssr.

When I try to change the  **baseURL** in nuxt.config.ts from **'/'** to **'/base'**
the page render correctly

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <AnimeSlider :season="getCurrentSeason()" />
    <v-card class="my-4" color="transparent" variant="flat">
      <v-card-title>
        Trends Of The Day
      </v-card-title>
      <SwiperTrendsSlider :swiperData="trendsOfTheDay?.results"></SwiperTrendsSlider>
      <v-card-title>
        Trends Of The Week
      </v-card-title>
      <SwiperTrendsSlider :swiperData="trendsOfTheWeek?.results"></SwiperTrendsSlider>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-for="genres in allGenres" class="my-4" color="transparent" variant="flat">
      <v-card-title class="mt-4"> {{ genres?.item?.title }} </v-card-title>
      <SwiperGenersSliders :swiperGenederData="genres?.data?.results" :swiperBreakPoints="genersBreakPoints"
        :mediaDataId="genres?.item">
      </SwiperGenersSliders>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup>

import SwiperTrendsSlider from "@/components/SwiperTrendsSlider.vue";

const { TMDBKEY } = useRuntimeConfig()

const { data: trendsOfTheDay } = await useFetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${TMDBKEY}&page=1`)

const { data: trendsOfTheWeek } = await useFetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=${TMDBKEY}&page=1`)
import { getCurrentSeason } from "~~/common/commonFuntions";
import AnimeSlider from "~~/components/AnimeSlider.vue";
import SwiperGenersSliders from "~~/components/SwiperGenersSliders.vue";




const genersBreakPoints = ref({
  640: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 20,
  },
  768: {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 20,
  },
  1024: {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    spaceBetween: 20,
  },
});


const { data: allGenres } = await useFetch("/api/genres");

definePageMeta({
  layout: "moviedetails",
  key: (route) => route.fullPath,
});
</script>

<style>
.ck-content * {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

This is the index.vue when the `baseUrl` set to something else than **'/'** the content of the page will called on the client side
but when the `baseUrl` set to something else all go right and the page render on server.

and help with this issue